# Shimano 105 rear derailleur is very noisy on bigger cogs

Tags: road-bike, shimano, derailleur-rear, noise

my Shimano RD-5800-GS rear derailleur is very noisy on bigger cogs, especially when
being in the bigger chainring at the front. On smaller cogs it's not so bad. I had this problem with it since i bough the bike second hand about a year ago. I think the noise is coming from the top jockey wheel as its coming in contact with the chain. Apart from this, the shifting is pretty much flawless.

I recently replaced the chain coming from the original KMC X11 to SRAM PC1110 but the noise is the same I'd say. I recently started using Squirt wax chain lube but the noise is the same as when using conventional chain oil. I also replaced the cassete coming from the 11-28 CS-5800 to a 11-32 CS-R7000 but it had no effect on the noise.

The jockey wheels spin freely and without a sound. I also tried adjusting the cable tension and b-screw but it had no effect. The noise seems to get worse when i wipe excess wax from the jockey wheels.

Edit: At first the video shows the drivetrain in the small chainring and bigger cog. Then I shift to the big chainring, then i shift to the smallest cog.

Comment: _bigger cogs, especially when being in the bigger chainring at the front_   Your doing what is referred to as cross chaining.  You're basically putting the chain at an angle to the gears which will be very much contributing to noise.  As chain path moves, it's not all that uncommon for noise to change, but cross chaining makes it worse

Comment: Yes I would expect it to be noisy when crosschaining on the big cog rear and front, but it is also very noisy when on the bigger gears back and small chainring. What bothers me is that it is substantially noisier than my other bikes.

Comment: I've had a similar issue with https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/89080/shimano-105-r5800-noise-on-largest-cog but I would say, the noise, especially at cross-chaining is perfectly normal, check my video posted there for reference, that was definitely off due to a bent hanger.

Answer (score 5):

The video demonstrates what is (to me, at least) a perfectly reasonable amount of noise from a chain crossed between the extremes of the cassette and chainrings.

That gear ratio is better achieved in the middle cassette with the smaller chainring. This is especially true if the noise from cross-chaining bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting because I had the EXACT observations and went through the same troubleshooting items you did. My previous bike did not have this issue but I was running a much smaller cassette in the rear (25 tooth max) I think. My new “endurance bike” has a 34 tooth in the back.

I don’t like the excess noise but admittedly I can’t push the bug gears that I used to and require the larger cassette in the rear.

If your pretty strong then my recommendation/theory is that if you installed a smaller cassette in the rear with a shorter cage derailleur then the noise would decrease significantly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Wouldn't this make the low end gearing significantly harder?  That doesn't seem like an optimal solution to some noise.